# Where did all the fancy equipment in Firewatch come from?

Tags: firewatch

In Firewatch you infiltrate a camp called "Wapiti station"

> The gear at the research camp includes 20ft radio masts, scientific instruments, enough chain-link fencing to surround the whole site, etc. We later learn that the whole scientific monitoring story was a facade invented by Ned. Given that Ned has been alone in the wilderness for years and that there is probably tens of thousands of dollars worth of gear that serves no real purpose in Wapiti station ...

my question is where did all of this stuff come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember learning anything about who set it up or why in-game, but by the end of the game there's no reason *(anymore)* to believe they were doing anything malicious.

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firewatch/comments/4r437n/can_someone_explain_the_wapiti_research_operation/d4y5658),

> The wapiti station is meant to be a university research camp doing soil samples and what not. The researchers had gone home for summer break.

[Another post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firewatch/comments/460l4n/spoiler_anyone_notice_the_name_of_wapiti_station/) claims it's a university research camp for tracking elk.

Comment: Thanks, the first like provides quite a convincing explanation.

Comment: One of the papers in Ned's hideout said something like about a date when the researchers would return. Still, the park service would know about any legit research operation of that size going on in the park...

Answer (score -6):

From the girls who insult you at the beginning

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate? What makes you say this? What in-game evidence supports this statement? A screenshot for a visual aide here (with a summary, of course) would be great.

Comment: I edited the question to be a little clearer that I am talking about the other camp, known as Wapiti Station.